# How to remove rainbow (pride) icon from sourcetree app?

Tags: macos, icons, sourcetree

I have a problem with Sourcetree App for Mac.
I do not like the new icon, I prefer the standard one. How to restore it?

Comment: It will change back at the end of this month. Can you wait that long?

Comment: @slhck - It fights that change, apparently. There's a method posted this morning on AD - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362676/how-do-i-change-icon-shown-in-dock-for-a-macos-app tbh, I don't know what all the fuss is about.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I don't see why you'd go to such great lengths to remove that. Feel free to post the actual answer (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-discussions/The-way-to-change-icon-for-Sourcetree-app/td-p/1110914) here though.

Comment: It can come as default but I think there should be an option to change it.

Comment: On the contrary, @Tetsujin, there's a solution for Google, too: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doodle-blocker-for-google/jfcifhfgpkjakpfmilfkfjnfabgmhpnl

Comment: It was fun for a day or two, but it broke my muscle memory of being able to cmd+tab/alt+tab over to Sourcetree by relying on the icon. So it's fair enough to ask how to change it back.

Answer (score 32):

Close the app, run this one liner:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/Pridetree/Bridetree/;' /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
```

Then restart the app.

You may want to backup Assets.car just in case you want the colourful logo back.

Answer (score 9):

Discovered on community.atlassian.com

> [**The way to change icon for Sourcetree app**](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-discussions/The-way-to-change-icon-for-Sourcetree-app/td-p/1110914)
>
> There is a solution how to change the icon for the Mac:
>
> 1. Launch the app from https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine
> 2. On the Sourcetree.app - right click - show package contents - Contents - resources.
> 3. Copy Assets.car and sourcetree.icns to any folder.
> 4. Run ThemeEngine.app (from extracted zip, above)
> 5. In ThemeEngine open Assets.car file
> 6. Extract icons from sourctree.icns file (simple copy-paste) and save new icons with Photoshop with 512x512 and 1024x1024 pixels. Or find
>    any icons for replacing.
> 7. Find the icon in the Assets.car with name Pridetree.
> 8. Copy a new icon (image) to the clipboard and paste to Pridetree icons.
> 9. Save the document.
> 10. Replace Assets.car in the app Contents/Resources folder version of my Sourcetree is 3.0.1
>
> Don't forget to create a backup file. Try this at your own risk.

Comment: This doesn¡t work.